# way to show more than 10 roles

Tags: usability, layout, ux-designer

Our users have more than 10 roles, they can shift between roles at any time.

Is there any way or design pattern to show > 10 roles on UI?

Below is sample: in image 1 there is a profile dropdown when user opens it all roles will be visible(Image 2) in which i have put all roles.

When user choose one of roles, that selected role's home screen will displayed.

With this user can do various tasks in various roles, he need not to logout and login every time to perform task in another role.

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Comment: Give us the rough idea, what you have thought of. As it all depends on your UI.

Comment: What do the roles affect - the entirety of the page, which components are shown, or something else? Do users typically switch roles frequently, or perhaps following some typical role sequence?

Comment: Why isn't the dropdown menu working for you?

Comment: We wanted to separate roles from user dropdown and we wanted to display more than 10 roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your definition of a Role?

A very common purpose of a Role is that it is a labour saving approach to assign permissions to a user, e.g. if you have lots of permissions in your system, it could take a long time to set up a new user up each time because you need to select each individual permission.

However, by using roles, new users can now just be assigned a simple role, rather than a large collection of individual permissions.

So if a person has several Roles, it just means they have a larger collection of permissions.

By using this approach, there would be no need for the user to switch from one Role to another, because your user profile would have all the permissions across all of the Roles that are assigned to them.

Obviously this all depends on your specific definition of a Role, and your solution design and architecture.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that came to mind was something like this:

[image: Vertical Tabs for Different Roles]